# 1 month old hdd acting weirdly, random 100% disk usage

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, performance, resource-usage

I have a brand new 4TB Seagate Barracuda HDD that I bought barely 4 weeks ago that seems to act weirdly since a few days.

I noticed that whenever theres any kind of activity(writing/reading)on the HDD, the hard drive turns super slow, and has 100% disk usage, and writes/read at less than 1mb/s when trying to do other operations at the same time on it (normally does about 160mb/s write and read speed when under no load).

For example, yesterday, I was downloading 2 600mb files from 2 websites, the files were being downloaded slowly (50kb/s) due to websites restrictions, so there was about 3hrs left of download. These 2 files where being downloaded on that Seagate HDD.

I left my PC running and came back 3hrs later, the files were done downloading (600/600mb) but seemed to be on hold to be copied on the hdd, and the HDD was again at 100% disk usage and terribly slow...

If I try to turn off the PC while this HDD is stuck/frozen at 100% disk usage, the PC half turns off, everything seems to turn off but the power light only turns off(to indicate that the PC is REALLY completely off) 2-3mins+ after the system has turned off; wich makes me guess that it is because of the HDD that is stuck/frozen at 100% disk usage and the PC is waiting for it to turn off..

Opening a program installed on that HDD can sometime take a while and when I do so, again the disk goes to 100% disk usage, and even after closing the program the disk still remains at 100% even when no copy operation or program running on that HDD are being executed... The 100% disk usage can remain a good 5mins after closing down application that were running from it, before the disk usage finally goes back to normal(0%).

If I try to copy several big files on it, disk jumps to 100% again, and if I cancel the copy, the disk still stays at 100% for a few minutes before going back to 0%... Running games from the HDD works just fine..

This 100% disk usage seems to happens randomly and not everytime wich is weird. I tried to check in ressource monitor to see whats using all or most of the disk ressources, but its most of the time ''System''(wich is the write/read operation being executed on the at that time HDD(file copy, application running on it etc..) and nothing else really..

I tried to run Seatools(Seagate drive testing software) tests on it, and all tests passed succesfully

I only have 7 days left to return this HDD, so I am wondering if someone ever had that issue with Barracuda HDD, or know what could be the problem. Like I said the HDD is brand new..

Thank you

EDIT: Screenshot of the HDD health informations:[image: Seagate Barracuda 4TB informations]

Comment: Normal work should not do this. Summarize the above thoughts in a concise note and return it rather than take time troubleshooting it.

Comment: “I only have 7 days left to return this HDD…” Just return it as defective and get a new one. If you have a lack of confidence already it won’t go away unless you get a new drive.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Im thinking of just getting a refund for this one and going with Western Digital HDD instead.. Never had issue with WD, and this is the second time I have problems with Seagate... I went with seagate because this HDD had 254mb cache vs 64mb cache on the Western digital one...

Comment: What do the SMART stats on the disk say? I've recieved new disks that already had current pending sectors and a high raw read error rate. back to the distributor they went.

Comment: @MartinB. Sounds like a plan! But I would recommend doing something to return the drive and get it out of your hands before it turns into a useless paperweight.

Comment: @FrankThomas How do I read that? I have the data but I dont know what they mean

Comment: post a pic or the text output. we can tell you.

Comment: 7 days?  Seagate offers a 3 year warranty on its  drives. or did last time I checked.

Comment: @Jasen on Barracuda drives, its 2 years. But you have to go through the whole process of seagate return, wich can take a little while. I am saying 30 days because I bought it on amazon, and have 30 days to return it, wich is a much more fast return process

Comment: @FrankThomas I just decided to return it and I bought a Western Digital blue drive instead of the same capacity. It has 64mb cache instead of 256mb that the seagate had, but I doubt there will be major performance differences since both drive are 5400rpm. Let's see if the same 100% disk usage occurs again with this one. For now it works fine, but I just plugged it in its brand new. Will keep you updated. Thank you

Comment: good call. you should not be having issues with a month old disk, and if they;ll take the return, that's just as well. Also if it helps, I don't buy high-capacity disks unless they have a 5-year warranty, though for smaller system OS disks or whatever I might get a cheaper one (but I won't cry if it goes belly-up). always had luck with HGST enterprise disks.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yeah well the one I bought is a 4TB Western Digital Blue,5400rpm,64mb cache. Never had issues with Western Digital in the past, but had problems with Seagate HDD twice.I am mainly buying it just for storage purpose, performance is not a main requirement for my needs with it. It has a 2year warranty. Hopefully it wont do the same thing as with the Seagate one I just returned.For now it seems to work as expected.

Comment: @FrankThomas I forgot I had took a screenshot of the  read error rate of the Seagate HDD I returned, I edited my post with the screenshot. What do you think? were those value normal?

Comment: Acttually on that level it looks healthy. the issue may be the logic controller. There is some activity in Read and Seek errors, but its within spec  so far. my guess is you haven't run a full disk check in thorough-mode, so it wouldn't have accumulated many current pending sectors for reallocation. that said though, if its only been used for a month, the growth rate of errors might have gotten intolerable very quickly. it was a good choice to replace it.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you. I indeed have not run a full disk check in. Hopefully the issue is not hardware related(PC motherbord or cable issue).. We will see. I will give an update if something happens again

Comment: I always do a full disk check on new disks (its a real pain, for high capacity disks it could take 8+ hours), just to make sure I can give them a workout and to make sure the SMART stats can populate for any problems encountered. I haven't had to send back many parts over the years; probably half of them were hard disks. they just don't ship well.

Comment: @FrankThomas what do you use to do the full disk check?

Comment: I usually quickformat it for NTFS and then run `chkdsk /f /r`. that will go over the whole surface of the disk, and note/reallocate any bad sectors. that gives it sufficient execerise to start to turn up issues in the stats (though I've recieved new drives that already had negative stats recorded). Read Errors and CurrentPending/Reallocated sectors are the two items I worry most about, because they impact the safety of your data, not just the disks performance/age. generally bad sectors increase exponentially, so if you get more than a few, they are likely to accelerate in growth.

Comment: @FrankThomas Ok thank you. I didnt do that but so far my new Western Digital one seems to work more normally than the seagate I returned. Installing a game on it doesnt make the HDD activity jump to 100% usage like it was with the seagate, but instead stays at a much lower usage(<10%)

Comment: What are the IOPS when the 100% disk usage occurs, as usually it occurs once IOPS have been saturated, which is normal for a mechanical HDD, as they're severely limited by IOPS.

Comment: They returned the drive @JW0914

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP returned the drive.